# register_post_type for Pages?

Tags: functions

Been reading this site and Wordpress Codex and I see there is a function to enable custom type of pages in Wordpress. How can I do the same to enable for Pages ?

Or at least get the options for the posts to appear for placing the posts under Pages ?

Comment: I don't understand what it is you're trying to do.  Could you please expand on your question a little bit?

Comment: Super late, but just adding clarification. Pages in WordPress are actually custom post types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you question is not so clear for understand. Anyway i try to respond... You can use 'hierarchical' => true when you declarate you new custom post type.

For placing this new menu in some other position in your admin are use the proprety 'menu_position' => 5,.

Example (to add in your functions.php file):

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_my_post_types' );    

function create_my_post_types() {
    register_post_type( 'mycustompages',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'My custom pages' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'My custom page' )
            ),
            'public' => true,
            'hierarchical' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'comments', 'trackbacks', 'author', 'excerpt', 'custom-fields', 'thumbnail' ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'mypage', 'with_front' => false ),
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Yip that was it. Started playing around last night and switch the hierarchical to true made it a page. Thanks !